# Uninitialized constant Project (NameError) in setting up Figaro gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I updated a Rails 2.3 app to 3.2 and it seemed to be a pretty simple process but when setting up the Figaro gem I came across this error:

```
C:\Sites\JustManage>rails generate figaro:install
C:/Sites/JustManage/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized
 constant Projectmanagement (NameError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
/lib/rails/commands.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Here is what my **environment.rb** looks like:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
Projectmanagement::Application.initialize!
```

Here is my **application.rb** file:

```
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

if defined?(Bundler)
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
end

module Railsapp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    config.filter_parameters += [
      :password,
      :password_clear,
      :password_verify
    ]

    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.version = '1.0'

  end
end
```

I've never run into this error before and don't know why it's happening.

Comment: Could you please post your `config/application.rb` file here too?

Comment: Of course, just one second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the name of your application is not the same in the different places it needs to appear in. Check the following files and see if they contain either `Projectmanagement::Application` or `Railsapp::Application`:

- config/application.rb (Actually initializes the constant)
- config/environment.rb
- config/environments/development.rb
- config/environments/production.rb
- config/environments/test.rb
- config/initializers/secret_token.rb
- config/initializers/session_store.rb
- config/mongoid.yml (if using Mongoid)
- config/routes.rb
- config.ru
- Rakefile
- app/views/layouts/application.html.erb, in title tag

Then pick a name (either `Projectmanagement` or `Railsapp`) and change all the names in the above files so they match. That should resolve the uninitialized constant error you are having.

Comment: That's awesome man. It was that little piece of code that says `Module railsapp` that was causing the issue. I knew it had to be something simple because it just started happening. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I ran into the same problem when trying to deploy on OpenShift.  OpenShift wants you to merge in their sample app to get their settings and hooks, but it changes things it shouldn't change. Thanks for the assist in sorting things out.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be certain that they are not errors from copy/pasting, but your `application.rb` appears to be incorrect. Issues I see:

- L1: You are requiring `application.rb` a second time where you mean to be requiring `boot.rb`.
- L12: The name of this module (i.e. the name of your app) is not consistent here with what is in your `environment.rb` file (`Railsapp` vs. `Projectmanagement`).

The second issue is actually causing the error you are seeing - you have not defined the `Projectmanagement` constant before calling a method on it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Would you mind elaborating a little bit more on that first issue that you noted?